# What do I need to style for the page after wp_get_archives?

Tags: archives, wp-get-archives

http://summitcoach.web.dmitcapstone.ca/

Just a development server for now, but on the blog page I have links for monthly archives but they go to some page I believe is date.php and I just want the posts to display as they do on the blog page, but only for that month. For some reason I can't find a single thing online about this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), archives are usually displayed using the theme's archive.php file, although other template pages might be used instead (see the image on that page).

So, you would need to change your theme's archive.php file, or change the font-page.php or home.php template (again, see the image on the above page).

I suspect that the home.php template file is set up differently than the archive.php template. Change the archive.php file to match what you need.

Of course, Child Themes are the best to do this change, as you don't want to change a theme's files - any changes will be overwritten with a theme update.